# Use multiple Heroku apps for load balancing Nginx

Tags: node.js, performance, nginx, heroku, load-balancing

I need to design one system requiring:

- 1 Node.js Server is used for reversed proxy for load balancing by using Nginx.
- 4 Node.js Server is used for RESTful APIs. All of them need to be connected to the server above.

I found out that no solution for specifying in case of using multiple **heroku apps** for load balancing. What should I configure `nginx.conf.erb` file in the first server to connect 4 Heroku server in the right way? I try implementing like this link http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/load_balancing.html but I just only receive `400 base request`.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku Round-Robin Load Balancing

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    location / {
        set_formatted_local_time $upstream "%S";
        if ($upstream ~ 00|01|02|03|04|05|06|07|08|09|10|11|12|13|14|15) {
            set $backend_url http://phpmyadmin-heroku.herokuapp.com;
            set $backend_host phpmyadmin-heroku.herokuapp.com;
        }
        if ($upstream ~ 16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28|29|30) {
            set $backend_url https://helloenvoy.herokuapp.com;
            set $backend_host helloenvoy.herokuapp.com;
        }
        if ($upstream ~ 31|32|33|34|35|36|37|38|39|40|41|42|43|44|45) {
            set $backend_url http://powr.herokuapp.com;
            set $backend_host powr.herokuapp.com;
        }
        if ($upstream ~ 46|47|48|49|50|51|52|53|54|55|56|57|58|59) {
            set $backend_url https://blog.heroku.com;
            set $backend_host blog.heroku.com;
        }
        proxy_pass $backend_url;
        proxy_set_header Host $backend_host;
    }
    location /load_balancing_heroku_resolver1 {
        proxy_pass http://phpmyadmin-heroku.herokuapp.com;
    }
    location /load_balancing_heroku_resolver2 {
        proxy_pass https://helloenvoy.herokuapp.com;
    }
    location /load_balancing_heroku_resolver3 {
        proxy_pass http://powr.herokuapp.com;
    }
    location /load_balancing_heroku_resolver4 {
        proxy_pass https://blog.heroku.com;
    }
}
```